# ExcelToCI error upload to PS_TRAINING record

Tags: peoplesoft, peoplesoft-app-engine

This week I started working on what I thought was a fairly straight forward data load using the ExcelToCI tool.  I am no expert with this tool, but I have also used it enough to have some familiarity with ExcelToCI.  The problem that I am having is using ExcelToCI to insert PS_TRAINING records for existing employees.  No matter what I have tried so far, I keep getting an error: "Please enter Course Start Date", but there is already a start date entered in my excel file.

I know this is not a date formatting issue in Excel, since the Course End Date field is able to update without any issues

Is there anything in App Designer that I can tweak to make this CI work?

I am stumped, anyone experience this or have any advice?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

There is a ci tester that you can launch from app designer.

Also there is a mode, CREATE, UPDATE, UPDATEDATA, on the 2nd tab of the spreadsheet.  You may need to change the mode.